# React hooks state Management

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using hooks in my react project.
I have written a function to manage the state in hooks.
but I don't know if it is Optimal.

This is my function:
mapStateToDOM.js

```
import {useState} from 'react';

const mspStateToDOM = (initialState, state) => {
    Object.keys(initialState).map(item => {
        let [current, setCurrent] = useState(initialState[item]);
        state[item] = {get: () => current, set: setCurrent};
    });
};
export default mspStateToDOM;
```

And with it, I can get a variable from state by using `state.varName.get()`
And I can change a variable by using `state.varName.set(SOME_VALUE)`

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import mspStateToDOM from '../config/mapStateToDOM/mapStateToDOM';

const Counter = () => {
    const state = {};
    const initialState = {
        count: 5,
        count2: 6
    };
    mspStateToDOM(initialState, state);
    return (
        <div>
            <p>You clicked {state.count.get()} times</p>
            <button
                onClick={() => {
                    state.count.set(state.count.get() + 1);
                }}>
                Click Me!
            </button>
        </div>
    )
};
export default Counter;
```

This makes the code much cleaner, readable, and easier to use. and I don't have to define a setter for each variable and use 'useState' many times in my code.
but I don't know if it is optimal. Is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use hooks inside a loop\callback as stated in [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

Therefore, such code is error-prone, **the only reason you don't get a warning as the linter can't guess it's a custom hook**.

Try adding `use` prefix to your custom hook name and see the warning:

> React Hook `useState` cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function. (**react-hooks/rules-of-hooks**)

```
const useMapStateToProps = (initialState, state) => {
  Object.keys(initialState).map(item => {
    let [current, setCurrent] = useState(initialState[item]);
    state[item] = { get: () => current, set: setCurrent };
  });
};
```

Moreover, there are few bugs in this snippet:

1. `state` and `initialState` will re-assign on every render.
2. Use of `map` without a return value.
3. Rules of Hooks as stated above.
4. Not a bug but in those snippets, it seems you trying to use OOP approach which comes from classes, in a function, while hooks motivate you for functional programming.

[image: Edit gracious-bassi-1q3s6]

- Refer to [Using Custom Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html#using-a-custom-hook)

Comment: Pointed well in the answer. As stated you could have used class based component. Plus functional unit testing becomes a challenge here!

Answer (score 0):

To add to what has been said by Dennis Vash.

This line: `state.count.set(state.count.get() + 1)` can easily be replaced by `state.count.set(prevState => { return prevState + 1 })`

Also, I suggest doing

```
const state = {};
const initialState = {
        count: 5,
        count2: 6
};

const Counter = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);
    return (
        <div>
            <p>You clicked {state.count} times</p>
            <button
                onClick={() => {
                    setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, count: prevState.count + 1 }) );
                }}>
                Click Me!
            </button>
        </div>
    )
};
```

No need to overcomplicate things.

But what's with `count2`? It hasn't been used anywhere.

Comment: Is it optimal? I think it re-renders every component using state on each setState...

Comment: Yes that's the expected behavior.